# Number of functions when mapping to the same set

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Say we have the set $A: \{1,2,3,4,5\}$

The cardinality of set $A$ is $5$. Does this mean that the number of functions to map set $A$ to set $A$ would be $5^5$?

If not, how would I go about figuring out how many functions exist for this situtation?

Comment: For each element in the domain you have 5 elements you could map it to. This gives $5^5$ options in total.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. In fact, this can be generalized. Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are finite sets with cardinality $n$ and $m$. Then let the elements of the set be $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ and the elements of $B$ be $b_1,b_2,\dots,b_m$. Now suppose $f$ is some function from $A$ to $B$. Then $f(a_1)$ can be any of $m$ options ($b_1$ through $b_m$. The same is true of $f(a_2)$ through $f(a_n)$. As such, we have $n$ different elements ($a_1$ through $a_n$), each of which can map to $m$ different things ($b_1$ through $b_m$) for a total of $m^n$.